# REST API & authentication (sign up / login)

Tags: rest, api, authentication

### Situation:

I'm creating REST API. It's quite simple, but there is a couple of things I don't understand:

1. How to do authentication (what route is the best). I thought about these routes, but I don't know what is the best: `/api/v1/auth`, `/api/v1/user/auth`
2. I don't know what method to use (GET or POST)
3. What about admins (I'll need a route to authenticate admins)
4. What method it's better to use (GET or POST) for `/api/v1/signup`, `api/v1/login`. Or it's better to use `/api/v1/user/signup|login`.

### PS:

I use in my examples `/api/v1/user - without s`, because I created routes:

1. GET `/api/v1/users` - gives all users
2. GET `/api/v1/users/:id` - gives user with particular id

Am I right about this routes&

Comment: What kind of authentication?

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin I'm using google, facebook, and other social networks for authenticating (OAuth)